# Low crosstalk opamps (Burr-Brown)

Tags: operational-amplifier, crosstalk

I stumbled across some information about an opamp on the Texas Instruments Site, the OPA1604 and in the datasheet it says:

> These devices also feature completely independent circuitry for lowest crosstalk and freedom from interactions between channels, even when overdriven or overloaded.

I would like to construct 4 Howland current sources using a quad opamp and was worried about channel saturation (when a current source is disconnected from its load) affecting other channels on the same package, but this feature seems useful in handling it.

I am trying to gather whether this is more of a gimmick limited to this range of audiophile amps or whether I can find this style of opamp more generally also from other manufacturers? And how would I go about identifying them using parametric search ect..., or would I have to just have to churn through data sheets?

Comment: Why not use individual opamps then there is no problem.

Comment: Before you worry, attach some numbers to your concern.  How much interaction is too much?  10%?  0.1%?  0.001%?  As pointed out in the answer below, there will always be interactions.  In theory, there will be interactions between my typing this out and some rock on Mars -- so you can't ask for nothing, you have to ask for "small enough", and then you have to define that.

Comment: @TimWescott I think JPL just announced that a rock on Mars flipped onto its side about an hour ago. ;) Looks like you might be right about that!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's not normally a big factor in selection so distributor parametric searches don't allow for it, you might find some analog IC manufacturer that includes it, I don't think AD does.

It's normally not very important in circuit design, the only time I've seen it become at all significant is when one amplifier in the package is operating at \$\mu\$V at the input and the other is handling volts of output swing (and that was with 4558 op-amps which are not much more advanced than a 741). Golden-eared audiophiles might differ on that point, but recall that channel separation on LP records was only something like 25dB under ideal conditions. Even the lowly 4558 provides typical 105dB crosstalk attenuation at G=100 which is 10,000 times better.

Some of the crosstalk effect comes from shared internal bias networks, and separating those could reduce the effect, though not to zero. To me, anyway, it makes more sense to  use separate IC packages if crosstalk is all that important. Layout will almost surely be better, for example.

Answer (score 3):

You will always have HEAT interactions. Even if the layout of each front_end diffpair is the legendary cross_coupled quad, the metallization will have imbalances; given aluminum has about the same specific heat and thermal conductivity of silicon, there will be thermal interactions. The thermal timeconstant of 1mm (1,000 micron) silicon cube is 0.0114 seconds (11 milliSeconds), thus low base tones will be interacting via the silicon substrate.

And, with the shared VDD/GND pins, the high-frequency inductive bounce that far exceeds what Power Supply Rejection can exclude, will always intrude directly thru the output transistors to the I_hope_this_is_clean Vout.

And there will be electric fields thru the black plastic epoxy, particularly to/from the large_area compensation capacitors.

And magnetic fields, as "high currents" (10mA/10 nanoseconds for fast opamps, not audio) are predictable, but the conductive silicon substrate will attenuate.

And package pin_to_pin mutual inductance. Let us compute that: 10mA/10 microSeconds to support a 16KHz tone. With 1 nanoHenry pin_to_pin inductance.

Shall we assume 1 microvolt is acceptable level of crosstalk?

V = L * dI/dT = 1e-9 * (0.01amp/10uS) = 1e-9 * 1e-2/1e-5 = 1e-9 * 1e+3

V = 1e-6

Thus for higher audio tones, driving 10 milliAmps, the interaction is at 1uV level. What to do?

Comment: And on a bad day you'll have interactions bad enough to cause problems between two different chips on one board, and even from one board to another.  It just depends on how much isolation you need and how good (or poor) a job you did with the isolation.